# Can I assign users to different conditions in Google Analytics Content Experiments?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to set up an A/B study using Content Experiments in Google Analytics. The goal is to see if students are more likely to submit work depending on different invitations to do so: so two different invitation pages (A and B), seeing what gets better use results.

My issue is that students will be viewing the site a lot at school, sitting right next to another students and seeing what their screen looks like and talking to each other about the work. So instead of randomization per user as to what page they see, I want to assign entire schools or regions to different content conditions (A or B).

Is this possible?